# Using functions defined in typescript code from html

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following typescript files (pseudo code)
Calculator.ts

```
export class calculator{
  someFunction
}
```

Main.ts

```
Import calculator from calculator.ts

function callSomeFunction()
{
  Calculator.somefunction();
}
```

Question: if tsc compiler bundles and generates code using systemjs or some other module syntax, will I be able to call callSomeFunction method from html which has bundle.js as script reference.  If not then do I need to do window.callSomeFunction = callSomeFunction?  Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be for the JavaScript to attach listeners to elements *itself* - for the JavaScript (your entire bundle) to depend on the HTML markup, but for the HTML markup to not (directly) depend on your JavaScript.

For example, instead of

```
<button onclick="doSomething()">click</button>
```

do

```
<button class="some-button">click</button>
```

```
// JavaScript that gets bundled
document.querySelector('.some-button').addEventListener('click', doSomething);
```

This way, `doSomething` doesn't need to be global, and you get to avoid inline handlers (which should never be used anyway).

Comment: Thanks for your response.  The question I have is that "is callSomeFunction defined in main.ts" even available to the html/global space?  Or would I need to do window.callSomeFunction = callSomeFunction in main.ts?

Comment: You'd have to import it to the file in which you attach the listener, but it doesn't need to be global.